# PHP, strange "Invalid argument supplied for foreach" with typehint

Tags: php, arrays, casting, arguments

I have function like this:

```
function fo(array $ids){
  foreach($ids as $key => $val)
    do_something_simple_without_pointers_and_stuff_like_that($key, $val);
}
```

I know i can do "is_array check" but, how on earth is possible to got php warning "Invalid argument supplied for foreach()" when i have type hint in function params?

Comment: what are you passing as `$ids`

Comment: an array, but if i pass string or null, should i got "Catchable fatal error: Argument 1 passed to [ClassName]::__call() must be an instance of string, string given in [php_file_name] on line [line_number]"

Comment: what is your array structure? Is it iterable?

Comment: structure is like: array('string', 'string2', 'string3', ...)

Comment: Please provide a *complete*, self contained example that reproduces exactly that problem. In the snippet you show it *should* indeed be impossible to get that warning.

Comment: BTW, the function signature has a type *hint*, not a cast.

Comment: @deceze i edited confusion with hint/cast keyword and will look for more complete question when i log input params

Comment: Tino, i got exception on PHP 5.3.24:
>php -f t.php
array(0) {
}
PHP Catchable fatal error:  Argument 1 passed to arraycast() must be an array, string given, called in t.php on line 9 and defined in t.php on line 2
PHP Stack trace:
PHP   1. {main}() t.php:0
PHP   2. arraycast($ids = 'row') t.php:9

Catchable fatal error: Argument 1 passed to arraycast() must be an array, string given, called in t.php on line 9 and defined in t.php on line 2

Call Stack:
    0.0000     328808   1. {main}() t.php:0
    0.0000     328928   2. arraycast('row') t.php:9

Comment: deceze, the function signature has exactly type casting. Type hinting can be set using phpDoc

Comment: @Michael Nope. This type *hint* for function arguments will throw a fatal error when an argument which is not of that type is passed into the function. A *cast* simply converts anything to the requested type. Hint: `function (type $param)`. Cast: `$foo = (type)$bar`. http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.typehinting.php

Comment: @deceze, oops, my fault. Too used to typehinting in ide